# Gifs of finding the volume of 3d shapes?

Tags: secondary-education, examples, geometry

I'm looking for some animations (videos or gifs) of finding the volume of different 3d shapes. It would be super helpful if I could find something which stacks unit cubes into a rectangular prism to find how many of these unit cubes are able to fill up the entire prism. This concept leads into base area * height which leads into deriving the formula for a cylinder.

If anyone has anything, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit beyond what you had in mind, but here are [some GIF visualizations of the volume of cones and pyramids](http://ceemrr.com/Geometry2/Pyramid_Cone/Pyramid_Cone_print.html).

When I was trying to understand why cones and pyramid are one third the volume of prisms and cylinder's, this [visualization of Euclid's proof helped me](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXII/propXII7.html). Unfortunately, the Java applet no longer works (at least in my browser).

When I taught these volume formulae, I found that [geometric solid manipulatives that fill with water](http://www.hand2mind.com/item/giant-geometric-solids/1178) to be a good teaching tool.

Last, your students mind find some these [online virtual volume manipulatives](https://www.msu.edu/~stemproj/simulations%20-%20volume.html) helpful.

Answer (score 4):

These are a bit slow for my tastes, but ...

(1) Box a.k.a. Rectangular Prism
([YourTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWkKGYWWGqQ)):

---

[image: Volume]

---

(2) Cylinder
([ck12.org link](http://www.ck12.org/geometry/Surface-Area-and-Volume-of-Cylinders/lesson/Cylinders-Intermediate/)):

---

[image: Cylinder]

---

Answer (score 3):

Khan academy has a pretty good exercise covering this

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-fifth-grade-math/cc-5th-measurement-topic/cc-5th-volume-formula-intuition/e/volume-formula-intuition

Displays a rectangular prism which is precut into $n$ slices, by color.

Asks how many slices there are, how many cubes in each slice, and finally how many total cubes.